# Import Ant project into Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, ant

I am new to Ant. I have an existing Ant project and imported into Eclipse without any issues.

My actual project structure is as below outside eclipse:

[image]

But after importing into eclipse, I can see only `src` folder and `build.xml` and `referenced libraries` folder. I could not see other folders inside eclipse. It is web application and `EAR` file is created.

Do i need to convert the project as eclipse project to see all the folders? Like `eclipse:eclipse` for maven projects is there any command for Ant projects? Please help me.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain how you imported the project inside eclipse ?

Comment: File-->New--->Other--->Java Project From Existing Build File

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing ant build.xml in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880350/importing-ant-build-xml-in-eclipse)