# Existing Ant project and Dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I'm new to Ant so sorry for potentially stupid question.

I have an existing project with build.xml. It has only src folder. I successfully opened it in Eclipse and I can build it with Ant (I'm getting dist/build/javadoc) folders, everything is fine and defined dependencies are resolved there.

*What I want to get?*
I would like to start to develop, but I have no idea how can I resolve dependencies and what are my next steps. All the files are in errors in the src folder. Can someone provide any recommendations or links to read? 
Thanks.

UPD:
What I can do - add all dependencies as External Jars. But is it a right way of doing things?

Comment: You need to configure Build Path in Eclipse so Eclipse can check dependencies. To do so, right-click on your project in Eclipse Project Explorer then Build Path > Configure Build Path. Add source folders or jar dependencies / libraries here.

Comment: try importing your project in eclipse as specified in the comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23243941/import-ant-project-into-eclipse).