# Import Ant Project from Github

Tags: eclipse, git, tomcat, github, ant

I have been trying to import [Tomcat Project from Github](https://github.com/apache/tomcat) in Eclipse,
but it is not importing as Java Project . Please explain a step by step guide to import Ant Project from Github to Eclipse.

I tried using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880350/importing-ant-build-xml-in-eclipse) answered question on stackoverflow but project is getting imported fine but the git properties has gone missing.

Answer (score 0):

Try out the following:

```
1. Open Eclipse, select File > Import > Git > Projects from Git
2. Select Existing Local Repository, click on next
3. Click on Add > Browse, select the directory where you have stored the repo, click on OK > Finish, and select the newly added repository and click on Next
4. Select "Import as General Project" > Next > Finish
5. Click on Window > Show view > Ant
6. Drag the build.xml file into the view, and click on the green play button. Things ought to build as well.
```

[Reference](http://www.lennu.net/import-git-project-into-eclipse/) (with screen shots, although here they add a git repo that is online as opposed to already cloned and on the local disk).

Comment: @aspiring-sarge I have tried these steps, but the problem is its not imported as java project.

Comment: @KodeCeeper: I've added in a little more detail, changed things a little and tested it out on another repo that has both git and a build file, but no .project files. Does that help?