# How to import existing Ant build.xml into IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, ant, intellij-idea, build.xml

I have an existing project that uses an Ant `build.xml` file to maintain the location of dependency jars.

[In Eclipse it's very easy to import from an existing Ant file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880350/importing-ant-build-xml-in-eclipse). I have searched online and looked through all of the "new project" options in IntelliJ but cannot figure out how to do this.

The closest thing I've done is **File** > **New** > **Project from Existing Sources**. But my whole project is full of errors because it didn't use the `build.xml` to include the jars.

Answer (score 19):

Intellij supports Ant projects via built in Ant plugin which is included by default in IDE.
To check if it is enabled go to `Settings > Plugins > Ant`

After enabling plugin, you can use `build.xml` from `View > Tool Windows > Ant Build`

You should then have option(+) of importing your `build.xml` file.

Comment: Thanks, that does allow me to build. But when I'm viewing the code in the editor it's still littered with errors, which makes it pretty annoying to use. Do you know of a way to deal with that?

Comment: Do you see error even after running build? Does your project have multiple build files? Then you will have to add all files in `Ant` menu

Comment: Yes I see the errors after running build. No I don't have multiple `build.xml` files.

Comment: If build runs successfully, compilation errors should go away. Do you have external dependencies and are you sure they are downloaded(e.g in External Libraries folder)?

Comment: And yes the external dependencies are downloaded and properly referenced to in the `build.xml` file. I'm sure of this because the Ant import in Eclipse works flawlessly.

Comment: intellij may need `build.xml` to follow certain format. Please try checking if your `build.xml` is compatible to format mentioned [Intellij and Ant Files](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/ant.html#d784316e18570)

Comment: IntelliJ's editor does not use your Ant build file to figure out the classpath. You need to configure libraries on your project's module(s) separately (in the Project Structure dialog), and keep them in sync.

If you convert your build to use Maven or Gradle instead, this problem goes away, and you get a bunch of other nice benefits too. :D

Comment: @JakeRobb I wish I could convert to Maven or Gradle :) but as lower ranked dev on an existing project I did not have that option. It would be nice if IntelliJ copied the Eclipse feature that uses the Ant build file to determine the classpath but I understand why they wouldn't bother to add that.

Comment: As a lower ranked dev, if you did the work to convert (say, on a branch), that would save you and all of your coworkers a ton of time, which might then address the "lower-ranked" problem!

Answer (score 12):

You should use **File > New > Module** instead of **File > New > Project from Existing Sources** for Ant project. You also need to set your **Content root** and **Module file location** to your current Ant project directory.

You may also need to set right path to project output in **Project Structure > Use module compile output path** and set proper content route in **Project Structure > Sources**

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helped ! Strange that we can't import a full Ant project just as a Maven Project by selecting the main build.xml though.

Answer (score 11):

Import the project "from existing sources" without choosing any build tool (ant is not on the list, only maven, sbt, etc...). Then after completing the import wizard, in the project files view, right click ant's build.xml file, and choose the option relating to ant which is hiding at the bottom of the menu.

Comment: you mean "add as ant build file"?

Answer (score 2):

Please, follow the steps below if you use the IntellIj:

1. Check the Ant plugin for the project.

[image]

2. select the build.xml file and add as the Ant build file

[image]

3. Use the side button to deploy the project

[image]