# Intellij IDEA no option to import ant build file

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a project which uses ant build tool and the project uses

**IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3.1 (Community Edition)**

The most `frustrating` and `infuriating` part that I'm experiencing is
a process of importing build.xml file to ant window - it just doesn't
work whatever I try. And I've tried

```
Importing project from git
Importing project from sources
```

It just seems that the option to add `build.xml` file as an ant build file evades me.

The most **ridiculous** part is when I try to press `+` in an ant window and add build.xml it
does not allow me to select build.xml it just fails to show build.xml at all... Why?

What have I tried?

I've tried every single option written here

[How to import existing Ant build.xml into IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30402843/how-to-import-existing-ant-build-xml-into-intellij-idea)

My questions

1. How to add buil.xml file to Intellij IDEA?
2. Why I'm failing to add build.xml file `as an ant build` file while
   going though ant window `+` option?
3. Why I'm missing an option (right context menu) to add `build.xml`
   as an ant build file?

I've tried to build project using Eclipse and everything was working fine, but Intellij
just ignores `ant` why? Do I need Ultimate version? Is ant option available only in paid version of Intellij IDEA?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, my dear God, just found out how to import `ant build.xml` file

First I needed to override build.xml file type (click on an ant build.xml file -> select override file type -> select XML) and then second time I've clicked the right mouse button an extra option showed `add as ant build file`
showed up.

[image]

Comment: Just curious, is the file actual valid XML, i.e. does it start with `<?xml version="1.0"?>`

Comment: yes, build.xml is a valid xml file. And it starts with <?xml version="1.0"?>