# 'Java Project from Existing Ant Build File' option missing

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I am trying to import a Java project into `Eclipse` and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13989878/649497) states that I must use the `Java Project from Existing Ant Build File` to do this. Problem is that this option does not exist in my installation of `Eclipse`. Here is what I see when I select `File > New > Project`.

[image]

What do I need to install to get this option?

UPDATE:

Here are my version details for Eclipse:

[image]

It was installed on `Windows 10` via a download of `adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702.zip`. I have only used it for `Android` development to date, but now I need to port an application from `Java` to `Android` so am trying to create a project for the `Java` application.

Comment: Don't you have anything about ant in File > New > Other... ? Also, what is your version of Eclipse ?

Comment: Try Help>Install new software, then select "all available sites", and search and install "Eclipse Java Development Tools" .

Comment: Looks like Google either left the Ant tools out of their packaged Eclipse or they have hidden them. I don't know this package but look in the Preferences in 'General > Capabilities' to see if there is something you can enable.

Comment: @Berger You are right, the Eclipse Java Development Tools were left off this package. Installing them via Help>Install resolved the issue. Thanks.

Comment: @greg-449 Tools were indeed left out of the package. Thanks for the help.