# Sample Project Import in WSO2CEP Developer Studio fails

Tags: eclipse, sample, wso2-cep

I have just installed `eclipse-luno-with-developer-studio` and in need to make some changes in already created samples in `wso2cep` like the very first one, `http` but it isn't importing those samples. I can run those samples using

```
ant -Durl=http://localhost:9763/endpoints/httpReceiver -Dsn=0001
```

but I want to modify the source and try again. For that when I searched, I found above IDE but its not accepting these samples as project when I try to import it. Anyone with a clue?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer [importing ant build.xml in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880350/importing-ant-build-xml-in-eclipse).

> 1. Open Eclipse, select File > New > Project
> 2. Select "Java Project from Existing Ant Build File"
> 3. Show your build file and write a project name

For step 3, select the build.xml file related to the sample-project which you're trying to import.
For example, if you're trying to modify the HTTP producer, then you can point to following ant build file:
`<CEP_HOME>/samples/producers/http/build.xml`